Ansible Jinja2 Template dict in dict
I want to template php.ini configs for apache2 and cli. I filtered out the default options and added them to a dictionary like this:
php_config_options:
  cli:
    engine: "On"
    short_open_tag: "Off"
    precision: 14
    [...]
  apache2:
    engine: "On"
    short_open_tag: "Off"
    precision: 14
    [...]

I have put this under vars/Ubuntu-22.yaml so that I can configure it ongoing for the releases. My template looks like this:
{% if php_config_options[environment] is defined %}
{% for option, value in php_config_options[environment].items() %}
{{ option }} = {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}

and my task like this:
- name: setup | Template php.ini
  ansible.builtin.template:
    src: "{{ php_version }}/php.ini.j2"
    dest: /etc/php/{{ php_version }}/apache2/php.ini
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0644
  vars:
    environment: "apache2"

When I try to run it I got the Error dict object has no element [] but I don't know why. Can anyone help me here?
My idea is to use these default variables, but when I want to change one I will set this in either group_vars or host_vars and he picks this + the other default ones.

You may want to use {% if environment in php_config_options %}

FWIW, there must be libraries which can generate a valid INI file from a dict. Doing this via Jinja templating is extremely error prone. A stray newline or such and you'll mess up the INI syntax.

Because you're trying to create a PHP INI file…?!

Given the simplified dictionary
php_config_options:
  cli:
    engine: "On"
    short_open_tag: "Off"
    precision: 14

Use the filter community.general.to_ini. For example, the template
{{ php_config_options | community.general.to_ini }}

gives
[cli]
engine = On
short_open_tag = Off
precision = 14



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    php_config_options:
      cli:
        engine: "On"
        short_open_tag: "Off"
        precision: 14

  tasks:

    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/ansible/php.ini
        content: |
          {{ php_config_options | community.general.to_ini }}



It was a combination of both, but this is a more easy option. I just didin't use copy, I used template instead, but it worked. Beforehand I merged the dictionaries to another variable suffixed _merged

You can use it in a template file, content block, or elsewhere. The Jinja2 template is the same. The copy module was used for simplicity.

You should use community.general.ini_file module, which was designed exactly for your usecase - to tweak existing settings, without maintaining defaults yourself.
I created a minimal reproducible playbook to illustrate how you can map your yaml settings into existing ini file
Let's say we have a config.ini file inside playbook directory, with following contents:
[section0]
key0 = value0
[section1]
key1 = old_value

We can then execute the following playbook.yaml
- name: Generate ini from yaml
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    default_php_config_options:
      section1:
        key1: default_value
      section2:
        key2: default_value
      section3:
        key3: default_value
    php_config_options:
      section1:
        key1: value1
      section2:
        key2: value2
        key3: value4
  tasks:
    - name: Generate INI file from YAML variable
      community.general.ini_file:
        path: "{{ playbook_dir }}/config.ini"
        section: "{{ item.0 }}"
        option: "{{ item.1 }}"
        value: "{{ item.2 }}"
        mode: "0644"
      loop: >-
          {%- set results = [] -%}
          {%- for section in default_php_config_options | combine(php_config_options) | items -%}
          {%- for item in section.1.items() -%}
          {%- set _ = results.append([section.0, item.0, item.1]) %}
          {%- endfor -%}
          {%- endfor -%}
          {{ results }}

In this playbook we define 2 variables, default_php_config_options with default settings that need to be overriden and php_config_options which contain overrides for default options.
The output of command ansible-playbook playbook.yaml will contain
TASK [Generate INI file from YAML variable] 
changed: [localhost] => (item=['section1', 'key1', 'value1'])
changed: [localhost] => (item=['section2', 'key2', 'value2'])
changed: [localhost] => (item=['section2', 'key3', 'value4'])
changed: [localhost] => (item=['section3', 'key3', 'default_value'])

and the contents of file config.ini are
[section0]
key0 = value0
[section1]
key1 = value1
[section2]
key2 = value2
key3 = value4
[section3]
key3 = default_value

Notice that value of key1 in section1 was replaced, and missing options were added, while original section0 values remain unchanged.
Now about this loop, what are we doing - we are combining default_php_config_options with php_config_options, thus overriding former with values from later if present (see combine filter docs), and then for each key/value pair in each section we are creating list, containing

section
key name
value of that key

And executing init_file module for each generated list. I'm sure that other jinja-gurus can come up with clever function to solve same task, but I like my playbooks to be explicit.
The caveat is that if you'll delete something from default_php_config_options or in php_config_options, but in key, that wasn't present in defaults, it wont change already changed keys or sections back to default values. In that case you should either explicitly specify old value, or create a separate task to remove unneeded keys.
Edit: added combine example. default_php_config_options | combine(php_config_options) can be used with @Vladimir Botka example as well, but I'll leave my answer which gives an ability to work with existing ini files.

thanks for this nice answer, but I think that dosent fit my case. I want to have default values, an be able to override them. cli is an extra file, and apache too. That are not sections in one file. its urgent to have default values, e.g. in vars/main.yaml and be able to overrride them in e.g. host_vars, but without the need to specify them all.

Added example to combine some defaults with some non-default values

Thanks a lot. When I have the same option in both dictionarys, does then take ansible variable precedence place?

I solved this with the ansible.builtin.combine filter
